# keys for commands for using Ubuntu in Virtualbox in Mac

Tags: virtualbox, keybindings

I have installed Ubuntu in virtualbox in Mac. 
i open firefox in ubuntu, and want to find some word in a webpage by ctrl-f which I normally do without mac and virtualbox, but it invokes something else i.e. asking me if I want to make the ubuntu window full screen. what key shall I type?

also I will use emacs a lot in ubuntu in virtualbox, how shall I change keys?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the <kbd>Control</kbd> key shouldn't be getting confused in VirtualBox unless you specifically set it otherwise; both left and right <kbd>Control</kbd> keys should behave correctly when the VM is in context.

However, it *does* sound like you might have hit the <kbd>LeftCommand</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> combination which may be configured in VirtualBox as "tell VM to go full screen". I believe typically the left <kbd>Command</kbd> is the "host key" and operates as it would on OSX for things like hiding windows, quitting applications, etc. The <kbd>Command</kbd> key on the right of the keyboard is probably being passed down as the <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Windows</kbd> key to the VM.

All that being said, it sounds like you're hitting Command instead of Control and you're using the left instead of the right. These settings can be changed in the settings / preferences of VirtualBox if you want to modify it.

Comment: If I want to copy from outside virtual box to a text file inside virtualbox, how shall I do?

Comment: Unfortunately, that question is ambiguous; clipboard? drag-and-drop file? etc.    But as well, probably should be a separate question.